# $x^{5x}=y^y$, $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, find largest value of $x$.

Tags: exponentiation

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers satisfying $x^{5x} = y^y$. What is the largest possible value for $x$?

I'm stuck on this question in an Olympiad past paper. Anyone have any ideas about this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have:
$$x^{5x}=y^y<y^{5y} \implies x<y$$
As $x^{5x}=y^y$ and $x<y$, it follows that $x \mid y$. Substituting $y=kx$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$x^{5x}=(kx)^{kx} \implies x^5=(kx)^k \implies k^k=x^{5-k}$$
Clearly. $k<5$. Substituting $k=1,2,3,4$ :
$$k=1 \implies 1=x^4 \implies x=1 \implies (x,y)=(1,1)$$
$$k=2 \implies 4=x^3 \text{ (impossible)}$$
$$k=3 \implies 27=x^2 \text{ (impossible)}$$
$$k=4 \implies 256=x \implies (x,y)=(256,1024)$$

Thus, the solutions are $(x,y)=(1,1),(256,1024)$.

Comment: Why is x a factor of y?

Comment: Because the powers of the primes in the factorization of $x$ and $y$ are in proportion. This means that all the powers are greater (or equal) in one compared to the other, and thus, the smaller number, which is $x$, is a factor of the larger number, which is $y$.